# Agregar botón/Link para editar información de base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

tengo una tabla conectada a una base de datos en mysql y quiero que cada vez que se registre algo, que un boton este a un lado para poder editar la información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui tengo mi tabla

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-sm" id="tab_logic" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

            <thead>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">ID</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Nombre</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Puesto</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Departamento</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Antiguedad</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Reconocimientos</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from colaboradores') as $row) { // aca puedes hacer la consulta e iterarla con each. 
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['Id'] ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['Nombre'] ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['Puesto'] ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['Departamento'] ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['Antiguedad'] ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['Reconocimientos'] ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo. La más sencilla es con un link y al tocarlo ir a una página, `edit.php` (por ejemplo) donde se hará una consulta:

```
$link_edit = '<a href="edit.php?id='.$row['Id'].'">Editar</a>';
```

En la pagina `edit.php` capturas a `$id = $_GET['id'];` y luego haces una consulta SQL para traer el registro con ese ID y llenar un formulario para editarlo.

Si lo quieres en forma de botón, y estás usando [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) solo hay que ponerle `class="btn ..."`; o también se puede [con CSS](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+link+to+button).

Otra forma sería creando un formulario para cada registro, y mandando el id en un `input hidden`, pero me parece un trabajo innecesario si lo anterior ya funciona.

Answer (score 1):

En el encabezado debes agregar una nueva columna...

```
<td style="font-weight: bold;">Editar</td>
```

Luego en el ciclo, puedes:

1. Iterar el botón
2. Crearle un id para que sea único

```
<td class="text-center" id="<?php echo $row['Id'] ?>"><button>Editar</button></td>
```

Luego, con `javascript` o `jQuery` capturas el id y consultas toda la información del registro a través de `ajax`. *El siguiente código es a manera de ejemplo, lo debes adaptar en tu proyecto*...

```js
$('.text-center').click(function() {
  //Capturas el id del botón al que le hagas click
  let idCapturado = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(idCapturado);
  //Haces la petición ajax con el idCapturado
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" id="1"><button>Editar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" id="2"><button>Editar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" id="3"><button>Editar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Y finalmente, pones la respuesta de `ajax` en un formulario para editar los datos y eso sería todo.

*En la comunidad hay varios ejemplos del uso de `ajax`, por si no tienes el conocimiento.*